# Does gravitational force attract bodies with mass or with energy?

Tags: gravity, energy, mass

On my textbook is written that gravitational force is the force that attracts bodies with mass. But I've seen on a book that It actually attracts bodies with energy. I'm having a class tomorrow and I would like to know some argumments to use with - against my professor.

Comment: How about you just listen to the professor instead of creating arguments for him? The gravitational force by definition is $Gm_1m_2/r^2$, i.e. it depends on *mass*. Now "energy is mass" is a statement that is tossed around without actually much thought involved, so this may be what your book referred to. Anyway, ignore it and stick with mass.

Comment: So afterall, my book is right. Is that what you`re saying?

Comment: Within the context of Newtonian gravity, yes, all you need to worry about is mass. Your textbook is correct.

Comment: But considering general relativity It`s wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "wrong." I'd say it's an approximation, and a very good one at that.

Comment: But if I agree with my teacher I`ll be assuming that light isn`t massless, which she is, right? Last question, I promise, last question.

Comment: Before having this discussion it's necessary to establish whether you're talking about Newtonian gravity or general relativity. Either answer could be correct, depending on which framework you're using. (By the way, beingthebe, you should use the single quote, not the backtick, to represent an apostrophe when you type on this site. Backticks are used for code formatting.)

Comment: To start with, gravity doesn't mean 'attracting' stuff....It is pure geometry. You can predict the motion of a body on an uneven road using Newton's equations, or you can just say that the trajectory is along the road's surface i.e. how it changes. The latter, as it turns out, is the more accurate way. And in the actual universe, this 'curvature' is due to energy distribution. And that does not mean that energy doesn't encompass mass.

Answer (score 4):

In Newtonian gravity (what your textbook is talking about), the gravitational field couples to mass density, $\rho$. This is seen in the Poisson equation:

$$\nabla^2 \phi =4\pi G\rho$$

where $\phi$ is the gravitational potential. The argument you heard about energy comes from General Relativity, which is a more advanced (and more accurate/"correct") theory of gravitation. In GR, the gravitational field couples to the entire [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). The stress-energy tensor's components are energy density (which includes mass density by $E=mc^2$, kinetic energy, etc.), and momentum density. So gravity is really dependent on *energy and momentum*, not just mass.

Answer (score 0):

In relativity gravity is not a force anymore, instead it is geometry of spacetime. Therefore gravity (produced by energy which is equivalent to mass) would also attract massless particles without any force acting.